# Asynchronous Update in Web2py of a single instance

Tags: asynchronous, web2py

I am currently writing a program in web2py to control a dynamometer. It essentially mimics functionality provided by labview (ie. set the mode, direction, and speed/torque of dyno, query dyno speed). I want to be able to keep one instance of the dyno alive and update a print output of the value of the dyno's speed several times a seconds without having the user do anything. Is this possible and is there a way I can do this with scheduler or is there a better way I should go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to look into gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py. It contains an example in the docstring. You run it as a background process with Tornado and connect it to the instrument. It will push data to the page via a websocket and trigger execution of custom js.